# find value from subsequent row based on multiple conditions (without for loop)

Tags: r, matching

I have a large data frame with columns of data in the following structure:

```
    Event   Person_ID   Person_name Current_Result  
1   1       1           Greg        1               
2   1       2           John        2               
3   1       3           Tony        3               
4   2       1           Greg        3               
5   2       2           John        2               
6   2       4           Johanna     1               
7   3       1           Greg        2               
8   3       4           Johanna     1               
9   3       5           Lucy        3               
10  3       6           Mike        4
```

What I would like to do is add in a column at the end where I get the result a person achieves at the next event (event + 1) or NA if the person does not participate in the next event, like so:

```
    Event   Person_ID   Person_name Current_Result  Next_Result
1   1       1           Greg        1               3
2   1       2           John        2               2
3   1       3           Tony        3               NA
4   2       1           Greg        3               2
5   2       2           John        2               NA
6   2       4           Johanna     1               1
7   3       1           Greg        2               ...
8   3       4           Johanna     1               ...
9   3       5           Lucy        3               ...
10  3       6           Mike        4               ...
...
```

The events in the table have different numbers of participants and participants are not ordered. So I need some kind of function that looks for every row whether there is a person with the same Person_ID in event + 1 and returns the corresponding Current_Result.

I have managed to do so with a for-loop and subsetting but since the table is very large this takes pretty long to compute. I was wondering wether somebody has an idea on how to do it more effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I approached this with the thought of expanding the dataset to include all combinations of `Event` and `Person_ID` in order to correctly make the new column.  I removed the extra rows at the end.

First I tried this with the `expand` function, which is in the development version of the **tidyr** package (`devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyr")`) if need to install).  This expands the dataset to include all combinations of the columns of interest, which you can then join with the original dataset to add in rows for missing combinations.

The rest of the functions I used, including `left_join`, come from **dplyr**.  For each `Person_ID`, calculate the value of the next event with `mutate` and `lead`, then remove the extraneous rows with `filter`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    expand(Event, Person_ID) %>% # expand so have all combinations of Person_ID and Event
    left_join(dat) %>% # use left join with original dataset, NA filled in
    group_by(Person_ID) %>%
    mutate(Next_Result = lead(Current_Result, order_by = Event)) %>%
    filter(!is.na(Current_Result))

Source: local data frame [10 x 5]
Groups: Person_ID

   Person_ID Person_name Event Current_Result Next_Result
1          1        Greg     1              1           3
2          2        John     1              2           2
3          3        Tony     1              3          NA
4          1        Greg     2              3           2
5          2        John     2              2          NA
6          4     Johanna     2              1           1
7          1        Greg     3              2          NA
8          4     Johanna     3              1          NA
9          5        Lucy     3              3          NA
10         6        Mike     3              4          NA
```

I also played around with adding in the missing combinations by using `spread` from package **tidyr** and then re-`gather`ing that dataset back to a long format.  This seems a bit clunky, to be honest, but does add in missing combinations of `Event` and `Person_ID`.  The rest of the chain is the same as before.

```
dat %>%
    spread(Event, Current_Result) %>% # spread adds in NA if missing combinations
    gather(Event, Current_Result, 3:5) %>% # gather back to long format
    group_by(Person_ID) %>%
    mutate(Next_Result = lead(Current_Result, order_by = Event)) %>%
    filter(!is.na(Current_Result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data.frame is ordered according to Event:

```
aux1 <- split(df, df[,1])[-length(unique(df$Event))]
aux2 <- split(df, df[,1])[-1]
df$Next_Rresult <- c(as.vector(mapply(function(x, y) y$Current_Result[match(x$Person_ID, y$Person_ID)], aux1, aux2)), rep(NA, lapply(split(df, df[,1]), dim)[[length(unique(df$Event))]][1]))

df
   Event Person_ID Person_name Current_Result Next_Rresult
1      1         1        Greg              1            3
2      1         2        John              2            2
3      1         3        Tony              3           NA
4      2         1        Greg              3            2
5      2         2        John              2           NA
6      2         4     Johanna              1            1
7      3         1        Greg              2           NA
8      3         4     Johanna              1           NA
9      3         5        Lucy              3           NA
10     3         6        Mike              4           NA
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your answer! Unfortunately this approach produces an error on my system. (Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Next_Rresult", value = list(`485` = c(3,  : replacement has 382 rows, data has 5483). It might be because although the whole data frame is ordered by event values, some events are missing? I will check what exactly happened there tomorrow and give you some more detailed feedback.